# How to reduce multiple foreach in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the forEach section cleaner and nicer?

I will be making more `call_Funtions()`

I don't want to have to keep typing:

```
sentences.all.forEach((s, i) => {});
```

Just to remember which sentences have already been deleted.

---

**`sentence` object:**

```
sentences = {
    all:     [
        //100s of sentences will be placed here.
        "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
        "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
        "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
        "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
        "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever."
    ],
    push_into_here: {
        push_first: [],
        push_second:[],
        push_third: []
    }
}
```

---

**1st function:** that pushes then deletes the sentence that is true

```
function call_Funtion1(s, i, looking_for, move_to){ 
    check_for = new RegExp(looking_for, 'i');
    found_them = check_for.test(s);  
    if (found_them) {
        move_to.push(s)
        delete sentences.all[i]
    }
}
```

**2nd function:** that pushes then deletes the sentence that is true

```
function call_Funtion2(s, i, looking_for, move_to, para5, para6){ 
    //Code is running to check if this sentence is true
    if (/*this sentences is true*/) {
        //Do something
        //Do something else
        move_to.push(s)
        delete sentences.all[i]
    }
}
```

---

**`forEach`:** of the remaining sentences within `sentences.all`

```
//More call_Functions will be added
//Possibly 10 or more

//This will run first, deleting all matching sentences after being pushed
sentences.all.forEach((s, i) => {
    call_Funtion1(s, i, /First/g, push_into_here.push_first)
});
//This will run second, deleting all matching sentences after being pushed
sentences.all.forEach((s, i) => {
    call_Funtion2(s, i, /Second/g, push_into_here.push_second, para5, para6)
});
//This will run last, deleting all matching sentences after being pushed
sentences.all.forEach((s, i) => {
    call_Funtion1(s, i, /Last/g, push_into_here.push_third)
});
```

---

**What I've tried:**

```
//I tried doing this
//But it doesn't remember which ones were previously deleted

sentences.all.forEach((s, i) => {
    call_Funtion1(s, i, /First/g, push_into_here.push_first)
    call_Funtion2(s, i, /Second/g, push_into_here.push_second, para5, para6)
    call_Funtion1(s, i, /Last/g, push_into_here.push_third)
});
```

---

**Results Should be:**

```
    sentences = {
    all:     [
        //100s of sentences will be placed here.
        "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
        "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
        "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here."
    ],
    push_into_here: {
        push_first: [
            "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
            "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
            "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever."
        ],
        push_second:[
            "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
            "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
            "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever."
        ],
        push_third: [
            "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
            "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
            "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If the duplication is really bothering you, you could always just wrap the `sentences.all.forEach(...` in a function.

Comment: please add the wanted result of all.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to achieve. Could explain it more.

Comment: I added how the results should be

Comment: Why is the call to `call_Funtion1` different from the call to `call_Funtion2`?

Comment: you could probably use `Array.map.filter` to filter truthy statements and also don't delete sth from the array, cause it's gonna put an undefined in that index. use `slice`/`splice` for relatively __immutable/mutable__ deletion on array items.

Comment: 'call_Funtion2' has a different algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep `sentences` and add `"!!!End!!!"`

```
sentences = {
  all: [
    "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
    "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
    "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
    "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Second condition was met, so push and delete this ok forever.",
    "!!!End!!!"
],

push_into_here: {
    push_first: [],
    push_second: [],
    push_third: []
    },
}
```

Add These:

```
not_found = []
new_source = ["!!!End!!!"]
```

Add a **Reducing Function:** (Uncomment `console.log` to see reduction in progress)

```
function Reduce_Source() {
    x = not_found.slice(-1)
    y = new_source[new_source.length - 1]
    if (x == y) {
    //console.log(new_source)
    new_source = not_found
    not_found = []
    }
}
```

Add a **Filtering Function:**

```
function filterMatches(s, regexp, move_to) {
    return s.filter(function(str) {
        i = regexp.test(str)
        if (i) {
            move_to.push(str)
        }
        else {
            not_found.push(str)
            Reduce_Source()
        }
        return i
    });
}
```

Add these in which ever order you want to search and delete:

```
filterMatches(sentences.all, /First/, sentences.push_into_here.push_first)
filterMatches(new_source, /Second/, sentences.push_into_here.push_second)
filterMatches(new_source, /Last/, sentences.push_into_here.push_third)
```

---

## Working Demo

```js
sentences = {
  all: [
    "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
    "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
    "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.",
    "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.",
    "Second condition was met, so push and delete this ok forever.",
    "!!!End!!!"
  ],

  push_into_here: {
    push_first: [],
    push_second: [],
    push_third: []
  },
}

not_found = []

new_source = ["!!!End!!!"]

function Reduce_Source() {
  x = not_found.slice(-1)
  y = new_source[new_source.length - 1]
  if (x == y) {
    //console.log(new_source)
    new_source = not_found
    not_found = []
  }
}

function filterMatches(s, regexp, move_to) {
  return s.filter(function(str) {
    i = regexp.test(str)
    if (i) {
      move_to.push(str)
    } else {
      not_found.push(str)
      Reduce_Source()
    }
    return i
  });
}

filterMatches(sentences.all, /First/, sentences.push_into_here.push_first)
filterMatches(new_source, /Second/, sentences.push_into_here.push_second)
filterMatches(new_source, /Last/, sentences.push_into_here.push_third)
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(sentences, null, 2) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(not_found, null, 2) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(new_source, null, 2) + "</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="me"></div>
<div class="me2"></div>
<div class="me3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and filter the values and copying the sentences to the wanted arrays.

For every found string, an assigned function is called.

```js
var sentences = { all: ["First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "First condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.", "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.", "No conditions were met, so this sentence stays here.", "Last condition was met, so push and delete this forever.", "Second condition was met, so push and delete this forever."], push_into_here: { push_first: [], push_second: [], push_third: [] } },
    target = {
        First: { key: 'push_first', fn: function (s) { console.log(1, s); } },
        Second: { key: 'push_second', fn: function (s) { console.log(2, s); } },
        Last: { key: 'push_third', fn: function (s) { console.log(3, s); } }
    },
    regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(target).join('|'), 'g');

sentences.all = sentences.all.filter(function (s) {
    var temp = s.match(regex);

    if (temp) {
        target[temp[0]].fn(s);
        sentences.push_into_here[target[temp[0]].key].push(s);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

console.log(sentences);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is nice code… but I have to do them one by one… I will be prioritizing match features. So sentences will match to multiple functions… this is where prioritizing each functions comes into play. Each function will have a different number of paras.

Comment: Some functions will have more paras then others. I will have 10 types of functions.

Comment: you could use a function for every different search string.

Answer (score 0):

1) split up your function parameters and use filter:

```
 const call_Funtion1 =  (looking_for, move_to) => {
     const test = new RegExp(looking_for, 'i');
     return s => !(test.test(s)?move_to.push(s):0);
  };
```

2) chain the filter calls:

```
sentences.all = 
  sentences.all.filter(
    call_Funtion1(/First/g, push_into_here.push_first)
  ).filter(
    call_Funtion2( /Second/g, push_into_here.push_second, para5, para6)
  ).filter(
    call_Funtion1(/Last/g, push_into_here.push_third)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

As `delete` operations do not always yield the most efficient code, you could:

- Limit the functions to only return the validation result, excluding the move operations (delete, push).
- First determine where each value should go by building an array with destination names (`['push_first', 'push_first', 'push_third', null, ...]`, where `null` indicates an item should not move
- Then use `filter` to define the final arrays:

Code:

```
// Let your functions only return the validation result
function call_Funtion1(s, looking_for){ 
    check_for = new RegExp(looking_for, 'i');
    return check_for.test(s);
}

function call_Funtion2(s, looking_for, para5, para6){ 
    //Code is running to check if this sentence is true
    // Do something...
    return (/*this sentence is true*/);
}

// First determine where each element should go:
const targets = sentences.all.map((s, i) => {
    return call_Funtion1(s, /First/g) ? 'push_first'
        : call_Funtion2(s, /Second/g, 'para5', 'para6') ? 'push_second'
        : call_Funtion1(s, /Last/g) ? 'push_third'
        : null;
});

// Now move them using filter:
Object.keys(push_into_here).forEach((key) => {
    push_into_here[key] = sentences.all.filter( (s, i) => targets[i] == key );
});
sentences.all = sentences.all.filter( (s, i) => !targets[i] );
```